# Designing a complex button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make buttons using `CSS`, instead of using image sprites.

These are going to be across the site with different text, so making a large image sprite does not make sense, especially since the size of the buttons vary according to the text.

[image: back]

This is what I've been able to achieve : (very different from the original one)

[image: back-with-css]

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9CPBY/)

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #001151;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(32,70,97,.55);
    background: #002483;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
        rgba(0,36,131,1) 0%,
        rgba(0,44,151,1) 27%,
        rgba(0,61,166,1) 55%,
        rgba(15,77,180,1) 82%,
        rgba(23,83,185,1) 100%);
}
```

P.S. : (Browser Support >= IE9)

Is creating buttons like these possible using only `HTML + CSS`?

Comment: may I suggest doing a simple search on google for something like "css button generator", "html css buttons", "cool css html buttons"....you will get about 120348102834 websites that will help you achieve this, with ease.   :)

Comment: Split buttons into 3 vertical divs, the end divs having a static background image, the middle div having a repeating one.

Comment: It's definitely possible, if a bit complicated. I'd start by using one of these button-generators and then tweak from there: http://css3button.net/ or http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ or http://css3buttongenerator.com/ - good luck!

Comment: try this link http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-glossy-effect/

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this button is **ugly** :). The standard nowdays is to make buttons as simple as possible with very subtle gradients.

Comment: @A.O. : I tried, but failed to achieve this. I even tried exporting the image without text onto css gradient generator with image import option, the results are not resembling the original button

Comment: You will need at least one span inside the link, but the glowing effect over the "K" letter must be added only with background image

Comment: all the links provided above are very helpful and should get you started. Sure, you might not get it looking EXACTLY like the image, but you will get pretty darn close

Comment: @drip - you can use radial gradient background

Comment: @Cristy - not standard, but temporary fashion

Comment: Have you considered using an SVG as a background?

Comment: @cimmanon : Yup, still trying to, but as a last resort, wanted to attempt doing it in CSS first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get me wrong, but this button is ugly :). The standard nowdays is to make buttons as simple as possible with very subtle gradients.

Here is my try though, `CSS` only: http://jsfiddle.net/9CPBY/1/

I have used `before` to add the reflexion and `after` to add the spotlight glare.

```
a:after{
    content:".";
    position:absolute;
    color:transparent;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    background:white;
    top:5px;
    left:70%;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px 10px white;
    
}
```

Gradient generated using [ColorZilla's generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).
Only tested in Chrome, should work fine in other browsers too.

Comment: You, sir are a genius :)
I tried the same tool as you mentioned, however, got a very different result. Did you somehow split the buttons colors?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the fiddle you posted. I added 2 more `div`s using CSS pseudo-elements `before` and `after`. I needed one for the rectangular reflexion and one for the circle light in the top-right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that has glare. You need to do it with 2 `div`s

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/hZgxV/

HTML

```
<div id="blue_button" >
    <div class="blue_glare"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#blue_button {
margin-top:20px;
height: 30px; width: 150px; 
border-radius: 16px; 
border: 2px solid #ccc; 
text-align: center; 
background-color: rgba(60, 132, 198, 0.8); 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 90%, from(rgba(28, 91, 155, 0.8)), to(rgba(108, 191, 255, .9))); 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c5b9b, #6cbfff); 
border-top-color: #8ba2c1; 
border-right-color: #5890bf; 
border-bottom-color: #4f93ca; 
border-left-color: #768fa5; 
box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px; 
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.blue_glare {
top: 0;
left: 5px;
border-radius: 8px;
height: 1px;
width: 142px;
padding: 8px 0;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 95%, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
margin: 0 auto;255
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: doesn't look quite as sharp in crappy IE, but still a great example!

Answer (score -1):

CSS is fairly limited in this regard, unfortunately.  However, you could always embed an image into the CSS using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format.